# Find the first five terms (up to $x^3$) of the Taylor's Series around $x = 0$ of the function $f(x) = (1+x)^{1/x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm stuck on the expansion of $$f(x)=(1+x)^{1/x}$$ I've already tried converting it into some common Taylor's Series as follow  $$\ln(y) = \frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)$$ Expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ multiplying it by $\frac{1}{x}$ and then inputting the Taylors's series of $\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)$ into the Taylor's series of $e^x$ for calculating the following expression $$y = e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)}$$

$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + ...$$

$$\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x) = 1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3} - \frac{x^3}{4} + ...$$
$$e^t = 1+ t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3}{3!} + \frac{t^4}{4!} + ...$$

Now, the problem arises when I substitute $ t = \frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x) $

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)} = 1 + [1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3}+...] + \frac{1}{2!}[1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3}+...]^2 + \frac{1}{3!}[1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{3}+...]^3+...$$
No matter how many terms I calculate till $x^3$ I'll always get the same polynomials with different coefficients, this seems endless.

Through Wolfram Alpha, the answer has $e$ with every term and I don't know how can I do that?

But the answer is not correct, maybe I'm solving it all wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Direction is correct, so, most probably, you have some technical mistake. Can you show steps done?

Comment: @zkutch I've added the steps, the expansion of the $e$ part confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one trick to eliminate constants, may be it confuses you. Let me make it up to $2$:
$$e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)}=e\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)-1}=
e\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)\right)-1} =
e\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^2)} =\\=
e\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \left(1+ \frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^2) \right)=\\
=e\cdot \left(1 -\frac{x}{2} + \frac{(x/2)^2}{2!}+ o(x^2) \right) \cdot \left(1+ \frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^2) \right)$$
Hope, you can use this way to obtain answer up to $3$.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. The constants in the higher order >3 becomes just 1, this really helped.

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps more of a comment than an answer, but writing it in a comment box proved beyond my MathJax skills.  I suggest writing $$\exp\left(1-\frac x2+\frac{x^2}3-\frac{x^3}4+\frac{x^4}5-\frac{x^5}{6}\right)=e^1e^{-x/2}e^{x^2/3}e^{-x^3/4}e^{x^4/5}e^{-x^5/6}$$  Higher order terms won't effect terms of degree $\leq 5$.

We also only need to keep terms of degree $\leq5$ in each of the series, so it's a lot less work than the approach you were taking, I think.  There is a bunch of multiplication at the end, but we don't have to raise any polynomial to powers.